# Way to send a barcode via SMS with as little user interaction as possible

Tags: sms, automation, barcode

I would like to set up a bar code reading app (such as ZXing Team's Barcode Scanner) on an android phone in such way that it would send with as little user interaction as possible (preferably none) after the barcode was scanned the result in an SMS to a predefined phone number.

I have tried Tasker but without success and I don't have the skills to write an app of my own.

Comment: would you prefer an app that would do this explicitly?

Comment: What do you mean by explicitly? That the user has knowledge of the barcode being sent? (Yes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## **barsent**

<sup>....................................Weird name, I know right!</sup>

> barsent is a simple and free app that lets you set a predefined number in the
>   options and then any subsequent BarCode scan results will be sent to
>   that number instantly without any prompts.

*The [barcode reader by ZXing Team](http://www.appbrain.com/app/barcode-scanner/com.google.zxing.client.android) is however required for this app.*

## Get it here!

[**CLICK HERE TO DOWNLOAD THE BARSENT APK**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n38dyn7y2t25ver/barsent.apk?dl=0) (not available on market)

**Remember to turn on "install from unknown sources" in your options!**

---

Btw, the app is made by me when I got some spare time and I thought while it may be too simple, it could be helpful to a few people. Your question inspired me to make such an app (lol I know im such a sucker for bounties) ; anyway, it was fun getting this done in the [MIT's App-Inventor](http://beta.appinventor.mit.edu)

The app is not well tested because I did not have much time. If you find bugs or want to request for a feature, maybe we can do it over the <s>chat here on android stack exchange</s> or via email preferably. Comments are probably not the right way.

A few things I'd like to say

- Its simple and will always be free
- If its slow or crashing, I might not be able to do much really since its made using appinventor, do tell if those things happen though.
- If you don't like this, you can **[modify](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7pr6tz4yu2mdarg/barsent.zip?dl=0)** or build your own or ask me for features. Also, there could be potentially some apps in the market that does the same in a better way. I simply made this app for fun.
- I don't know if I can support app2sd or crunch the size of the app.. its just appinventor and I didn't include any fancy media into this app.
- There are no obtrusive ads, background services or airpush junk
- Permissions are exaggerated by the appinventor I guess
- Don't hold me responsible for anything
- If you like this, you can upvote this, share it using the small and cute buttons to the left of this post.
- Oh and after installing the app, I recommend scanning the barcode that's above in this post using the app. ;)
- Screen Shots.. maybe later but the app's really ugly in terms of looks. :D
- Exclusively for the stack exchange community! That's why I am posting here!

Comment: Oh, did that feel better! :D

Comment: Thank you very much! I never would have dreamed that somebody would write a program just for me! I would very much appreciate it if you could make the source code available because I'm a bit reluctant to install an apk from somebody I don't know without checking the code first.

Comment: @Andris I don't have a source code, but I do have the AppInventor's Project files. And you can build your own apk from it. I'll post it in a few minutes from now.

Comment: @Andris Here's the source files http://db.tt/PfYm9vJh Simply log in to App Inventor and in the projects menu, just upload this zip file on a whole.

Comment: Thank you! I will only be able to check out the project in a few days but in the meantime I will award you the bounty. You have definitively earned it.